# In hive, how can I get a map with a subset of keys, values

Tags: hive, hiveql

Lets say that I have a table `t` with column `x` of type `map<int, int>`

if I do

```
select x from t;
```

I get the full map, but what if I am interested in elements where the key is `1,3,5, 7`

Is there a way in hive to express this?

Answer (score 0):

you could select the elements as columns separately.

```
select x[1] as column_1 , x[3] column_2, x[5] column_3, 
x[7] as column_4 from t;
```

Comment: Never mind, I think I found the answer. Create a custom mapping function to construct a filtered output. The problem with the separate column approach is that I would have to modify the rest of the program